# mysql jodbc DB Connect problem - A cmd line app works fine. A servlet running same code on same DB, DriverManager.getConnection throws Exception

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I apologize for my confusion and ask if someone can help me to understand why I getting the behavior below. I'm using the MySQL connector v8.0.22 jar. I don't think it's important but I'm using Netbeans v12.

The servlet and cmd version are both runs on the same pc. Accessing the same DB.

The code has been cut and paste from :

https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

My question is, why am I getting an error in the servlet but not the cmd line ? Why is there a difference?

I have tried adding/removing ( re example in the link) :

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

NOTE: my db is called blood pressure and not sonoo. ( re example in the link )

The user I use is a full admin ( not root ) user.

The line in question is :

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodpressure","xxxx","xxxxx");
```

In the cmd line version it returns a valid con and runs a select. In the servlet, the getConnection throws an exception which exception is not the point. It's the fact that it does.

This should not make any difference but I've tried it on. Linux, MS - MySQL V5 and Mac - Version: 8.0.22 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) Compiled for Mac.

I've also tried with MySQL connector v 5 and v. 8.0.22

Would someone please explain or give me some ideas about why there is a difference?

I've tried lots of variations and done lots of googles but keep hitting the same problem.
Thanks

===========
Update as per Luke's request I created the same 2 projects, 1 java app, 1 Web App as I did in my previous attempt to resolve this problem.

Both use MySQL connector v 8.0.22, JDK 15

The code for the cmd line app is :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cmdlinedbtest;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jeff
 */
public class CmdLineDbTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
              try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodpressure","xxx","xxxxx");
//here sonoo is the database name, root is the username and root is the password
Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users");

while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

con.close();

}catch(Exception e){ 
    System.out.println(e);
}
    }
    
}
```

==========
The web is :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author jeff
 */
public class DbConnect extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet DbConnect</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet DbConnect at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bloodpressure", "xxxx", "xxxx");
//here sonoo is the database name, root is the username and root is the password
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from users");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    out.println("<br/>" + rs.getInt(1) + "<br/>  " + rs.getString(2) + "<br/>  " + rs.getString(3));
                }

                con.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e);
            }

        

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Again, the cmd line works and returns the rows of data.
The servlet throws Exception on connect.

Please help explain why the results differ.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't delete your old question and re-ask the same question just because the old one got closed as a duplicate.  Besides, I've never seen what you've described so I can only conclude that there must be something you're not telling us about your setup.

Comment: I actually reworded it to help the question I was asking would be clearer to read.  Its not a Comms Link issue or question.    It is why is there a differecne ?     The point is cmd line works fine, servlet does not.    Thanks.

Comment: The complete code was in my original post.  The only difference spotted was a typo in copy code into the question, hiding pass etc.

Comment: Both are using netbeans 12 ( The same made both projects ), both are including mysql-connector. v 8.0.22 ( The same jar for both ).  I do not know what more I can say.  If you think there is something missing please give me some guidence.

Comment: They are both run from the netbeans which made them.  Hence both are on the same pc.

Comment: I have tried using a db on a different server changing localhost to its ip of 192.168.0.12.   The local pc is 192.168.019.    The remote server works fine for both cmd line and servlet.

Comment: Using mysql workbench on 192.168.0.19. it connects to both local host and 192.168.0.12.    Using the same user, pass.     I used 192.168.0.12 via phpmyadmin to create a dump, which was used to load localhost ( 192.168.0.19).

Comment: The reason I want to use local host is to dev new versions before putting them on the live db which is on 192.168.0.12

Comment: Jus incase I also tried all permutations using an old version of mysql connetor v5.xx.  Again the same jar for both.    It made no difference. So I went back to v 8.0.22

Comment: Please tell me if there is anything else I should try ?

Comment: In saying all of that, deleted and opened because I thought a closed question could not be responded to. My apologies if I made a mistake.  But it was closed offering a solution which was not correct in this case.

Comment: I dont think is relevent but I've tried it.   Ive run the code & db on Linux v18.04, MS 10, Mac 10.15.   They were all buld with the same version of Java JDK.  The appserver is Payara V5.  Mysql was downlaod over the last few days to be latest. I think its v5.xxx

Comment: Deleting a question and re-asking it is basically an attempt to get around the fact that it was closed.  I note you've omitted the exception details, perhaps as an attempt to avoid getting closed again?  Anyway, the next task for you to do as part of the investigation is to create a minimal web application with only 1 servlet that does nothing more than connect to the MySQL database on localhost, runs 1 query against it.  If that works correctly, the difference is between your two web apps.  If it doesn't, edit the question to include the source of this minimal web app.

Answer (score 0):

As this has been troubling me for a while, I've of course been thinking about it and have come up with something.
My question why when the code/build is as identical as possible, does it work cmd line, errors in Servlet?

What is the diff?  The only diff I could think of is cmd line runs directly ( well being Java it runs in a JVM. I guess you could dismiss this as a constant and not relevant and I would guess the app server runs the same JVM, but I cannot be sure of that at this stage ).
The servlet runs via an appserver.
In my case, I had trouble with Tomcat 7 ages ago so swapped to using Payara which has worked fine on many projects.

So I figured, why not try a different app server.

A clean install of Tomcat 9 - no extra config, just as it comes.

IT WORKS........  YIPPPEEEEE.

I don't know why it works on Tomcat 9 and not Payara 5 but it does.
I hope this may help someone else as I've tried loads of so-called fixes, different ways of coding and like many got lost in the detail of the error and not the simple fact,   cmd line did not error, Servlet did.   The detail of the error is therefore misleading.    It is only the fact one works, one does not.

Thanks for any time, people have spent looking and trying to help.